# Android Studio - Gradle: How to replace variables in a file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Im fairly new to Gradle and have been using Eclipse and Ant to do all the builds. Within our app we have a config.properties file located in the assets folder at the same level as src and res etc. In this file we have the following:

```
developmentsettings=true
defaultLogLevel=4
prodEnvironment=false
```

How can I replace the values of these 3 variables in the build.gradle file? Do I create a new task for this, and if so, is this within the android tag or not?

Any and all help would be must appreciated

Comment: do your want to replace these values from your Android app?

Comment: Hi @Machado so depending if its a release of debug build I want to be able to change these to true/false etc, before build since the app uses these variables to configure itself. Hope that makes sense

So before I used ant and properties to change these values

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you specifically need these in a separate file... but if not, BuildConfig seems like the way to go.  You do something like this in your gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "boolean" "DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS" "true"
        buildConfigField "int" "DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL" "4"
        buildConfigField "boolean" "PROD_ENVIRONMENT" "false"
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "boolean" "DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS" "false"
        buildConfigField "int" "DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL" "4"
        buildConfigField "boolean" "PROD_ENVIRONMENT" "true"
    }
}
```

And then from your source android code, you reference these fields like so:

```
BuildConfig.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS
BuildConfig.DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL
BuildConfig.PROD_ENVIRONMENT
```

You're essentially declaring constants, from gradle, that can be used in your java code.

Comment: And for a `String` value do something like `buildConfigField "String", "URL", "\"http://yoururl.com\""`.  The value does need to be escaped.  You will see these generated in the `BuildConfig.java` file.

Comment: Is there a way to declare these "constants" at a higher level than the build types?  I don't particularly like having to repeat my constants for each and every build that I'm making (what if I miss one?).

Answer (score 2):

At build.gradle set the following

---

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug{
            resValue "string", "app_name", "My App Name Debug"
        }
        release {
            resValue "string", "app_name", "My App Name"
        }
    }
}
```

You can access them in the usual way with `@string/app_name` or `R.string.app_name`

Comment: but this wont change the values in the assets/config.properties though. is there anyway I can open the file, change the values and then write it back?

Answer (score 0):

You can let the build system include different versions of the **assets/config.properties** file depending on whether you're doing a debug or release build.  To do this, **don't** put the file in **src/main/res/assets/config.properties**; instead, put the debug version in **src/debug/res/assets/config.properties** and the release version in **src/release/res/assets/config.properties**. The build system will pick the right version when it does the corresponding build.

Comment: This makes sense. However @Scott Barta, currently the assets folder is at the same level as src. and in src, i dont have debug and release, I just have all the packages. so am I ok to create the debug and release folder structure or not?

Comment: Oh, to make that work you should rearrange your directory structure into a more typical Gradle-project-based structure. I take it you've just migrated this from Eclipse without rearranging the source?