# Best practice for accessing buildVariant-specific gradle properties (e.g. Release Notes) from library modules

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

Project has two product flavors each with a different applicationId (also different from package specified in base Manifest).

As is standard, this package is used for the BuildConfig class and R class etc.

What is the best way to programmatically know this package name (not applicationId) from within library modules?

I can think of a few messy workarounds like storing it in a resource, or AGAIN in the base manifest using a meta-data item:

```
<manifest package="com.company.myappbase">...
    <meta-data android:name="BUILD_CONFIG_PACKAGE" android:value="com.company.myappbase" />...
```

and so that can be accessed in the library using the Context.

Is there a proper way to do this?

My motivation is that I want a library module to have programmatic access to buildVariant-specific properties (e.g. Release Notes, Appstore target) defined in build.gradle.

Answer (score 3):

If the base package is already defined in build.gradle then you can use that:

```
android {
    applicationId "com.company.myappbase"
    // note: using ${applicationId} here will be exactly as above
    // and so NOT necessarily the applicationId of the generated APK
    manifestPlaceholders += [buildConfigPackage: "${applicationId}"]
}
```

If not (maybe because you didn't want the package name defined twice: in build.gradle and main/AndroidManifest.xml), you could read the package from the manfiest:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders += [buildConfigPackage: "${readBuildConfigPackage()}"]
        ...
    }
}
def readBuildConfigPackage() {
    def manifestFile = file(project.projectDir.absolutePath + '/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml')
    def xml = new XmlParser().parse(manifestFile)
    return xml.attributes()["package"].toString()
}
```

HT: http://toastdroid.com/2014/03/28/customizing-your-build-with-gradle/

In main/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application ... >
    <meta-data android:name="BUILD_CONFIG_PACKAGE" android:value="${buildConfigPackage}" />
```

In Java:

```
ApplicationInfo appInfo = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
String buildConfigPackage = (String)appInfo.metaData.get("BUILD_CONFIG_PACKAGE");
```

Answer (score 2):

My other answer works, but storing the package name in the Manifest's meta-data feels rather hacky.

Another solution (also hacky but maybe slightly less so) is to use Android's resources:

```
android {
    applicationId "com.company.myappbase"
    // note: using ${applicationId} here will be exactly as above
    // and so NOT necessarily the applicationId of the generated APK
    resValue "string", "build_config_package", "${applicationId}"
}
```

HT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28741526/444761

In Java:

```
int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("build_config_package", "string", context.getPackageName());
String buildConfigPackage = context.getString(resId);
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as

```
applicationId "com.foo.bar"
buildConfigField "String", "PACKAGENAME", "\"" + "${applicationId}" + "\""
```

Use it like

```
BuildConfig.PACKAGENAME
```

Comment: There is no point putting the package name in the BuildConfig because that is already available with `BuildConfig.class.getPackage()`

Comment: @MarkCarter Yep, didn't aware of that.